# How I can fetch data by couple parameters in Mongoose? (First is fetching by date Range and it's work but I need one more parameter)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem and I don't know how to fix this.
I have some orders that fetching by mongoose by range of date
But i need one more parameter that will fetch by range and if order is new.

there is my code:

```
       // fetch orders in current month
       const orders = await Order.find({
           createdAt: {
               $gte: start,
               $lte: end
            }
        })
```

I was trying to make something like this code below but it's not working..

```
       // fetch orders in current month which flag isNew
       const orders = await Order.find({
           createdAt: {
               $gte: start,
               $lte: end
            },
           
           isNew: true,
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your time guys. I find the answer by myself. For fetching data with more parameters all what need to do is just add another parameter to first method find():

```
find({parameter: one}).find({parameter: two});
```

It's so easy.. sorry again for your time.